# How to hide show menu from different component in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, show-hide, angular-ng-if

In my app component I have three component-

> app.component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

In my `app-header` component I have a nav bar with some navigation link,  I want to hide-show some link base on user login status.

> app-header.component.html

```
<nav>  
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >

    <li><a class="white" routerLink="/register"> Register</a></li>

    <li><a class="white" routerLink="/login"> Login</a></li>

    <li (click)="onLogOut()"><span> LogOut</span></li>

  </ul>
 </nav>
```

I am storing a token on `LocalStorage` when user login, so If this token have some value then I want to hide login and register link from `app-header component.` how can I achive this because these link are in heder component. And I am storing token in different component

Please suggest how can I achive this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using ngIF.

```
<app-header *ngIf != "localStorage.getItem("token") == ''"></app-header>
```

or

You can declare a variable in your component, check the with localStorage.getItem("token"). based on assign this true or false.

Comment: I want to hide only link not my app-hader component and this  component is not part of &lt;router-outlet&gt;&lt;/router-outlet&gt;
so if  i assign value it will not work because it will not load every time

Comment: I'm not sure with your question. but you can use localStorage.getItem("token") in any component.